# How do I access the loaded comment object?

Tags: 8, comments

I'm trying to access the comment field value in controller. With the following code I'm able to access the particular comment object.

```
$comment = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('comment')->load($commentID);
```

When I try print_r for the $comment variable, I can see the fully loaded comment object.
[image]

I understand I cannot access the values by traversing the object since the values are protected. I tried `$comment->get('subject')->value` function, this time its looping and doesn't return any results.

How do I achieve retrieving the value of specific fields associated with comment entity?

Comment: `$comment->get('subject')->value` seems OK, this should work.

Comment: Have a look at https://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet for all kinds of useful code snippets when working with entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use `kint()` function of the devel module for debugging entities because you will get also a list of available public methods.

You cannot get all comment fields values by looping them as different fields have different array result structure.

Using `$comment = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->load($commentID)` you get full comment object.

`$comment->get('comment_body)->value` you get comment body value as it uses some text format (eg. full html).

You also can covert comment object to array `$comment = $comment->toArray()`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend working with the return value of toArray() but it is very useful to use with kint()/debug()/var_dump(). It doesn't contain computed properties like ->entity, though.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Nim and Berdir, the kint() function of devel module  helps. PHP print_r should not be used for complex object with lot of iterations, I got it.